# Store passwords of Linux users in plain text - on purpose

Tags: users, password, shadow

I want to reset passwords temporarily to log in as root at least one time to change passwords. I have access to the hard drive and I can run a live distro to gain root access.

I did think it would be enough to change for each user the `x` in the second column of `/etc/passwd`, but this does not work.

Comment: basically you are asking how to reset a password - this is also already answered in [Resetting password of another Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/105278/1131)

Comment: Why do you think you need to store a password in plain text? You are almost certainly doing something complicated and useless. [Tell us what you really want to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I would like to recover hosts I cannot log on anymore. _I have access to the hard drive and I can run a live distro to gain root access._ Isn't there a way to regain control?

Answer (score 2):

The passwords are stored in the [**shadow**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html) file, not in `/etc/passwd`, so you need to delete the contents of the second column from `/etc/shadow`. An entry should look something like this:

```
root::16229:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: Did not work either. Neither an empty field nor any other record.

Comment: The second column records an encrypted password. How can I store a password in plain text there? Even if I remove a user from `/etc/shadow` at all, the second column in `/etc/passwd` is ignored.

Comment: No, there's no easy way to disable that, but you can generate a new "encrypted" one manually, for example by running [`openssl passwd -1`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/passwd.html) or the `crypt` function from C or some scripting language (e.g. [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/crypt.html#crypt.crypt), [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), etc.).

Comment: See also ["How to make user passwords shown as a clear text in Linux?"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145490/1174) here on the U&L SE.