# It is possible to recover a password (not reset) if you have access to root file system?

Tags: linux, passwd

If you have access to `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`, is it possible to figure out what the password is? I know you can reset it, but is there a way to recover it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145490/how-to-make-user-passwords-shown-as-a-clear-text-in-linux/145500

Comment: That isn't the same question.

Comment: Reference only. If it was the same I would've flag it as dupe instead of just commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, with sufficient time and computational power, yes.  But the entire point is that it's a one-way hash whereby the original password is supposed to be for practical purposes impossible to reverse-engineer from the hash.

Comment: You can't reverse-engineer the password, but you *can* brute force it. Having the encrypted password is the first step in a brute force attempt (since brute forcing any kind of login mechanism is ridiculously slow). Though, while I say *can* it still may not be a feasible thing to do depending on the password strength.

Comment: Hence the short answer being "yes" and the long answer being "yes, but not for practical purposes".

Comment: I'd argue both answers are "maybe". If the password is weak, the answer is yes. If the password is strong enough, the answer is no.